# What preposition should I use in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I'd never taken a glass-bottom boat. To be honest, the idea intimidated
>   me at the beginning. What if the glass couldn't support the
>   passenger's weight? **What if a shark swooped [...] and broke the glass?**

I searched on Google and found that [*swoop in*](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22swooped%20in%22&oq=%22swooped%20in%22&gs_l=serp.3..0l5j0i10l5.110683.112625.0.112803.12.12.0.0.0.0.322.1230.0j7j0j1.8.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..5.7.1113.cnTmM1E8EEc) is the most common phrase. But I don't know, maybe I should write *swoop up* since the glass is at the bottom of the boat?

Comment: I would change the wording to something like "What if a shark charged the boat, using its snout as a battering ram, and broke the glass?" In reality, sharks' snouts tend to be rather sensitive, which is why they tend to bite oars and other projecting objects (or limbs) more often than they punch holes in boat bottoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever adverb of direction (or particle in a phrasal verb) with *swoop* that makes sense in the context, just as you can with any other verb of motion. So all these make sense, just as a few examples:

- run/fly/swim/swoop up/down at us
- run/fly/swim/swoop in/out from below/above

For actual prepositional use, you’d need something like *swooped up the maelstrom*.

Answer (score 1):

Use "up" in this case (swooped up, swoop up), because the shark is coming from below, ostensibly.

However, I would not use "swoop" to describe what a shark does.  Swooping typically describes the action a bird or another animal would make where it flies down without using any flapping motions or motions to make it continue its downward arc - you can use this to describe other animals, or people as well, to give a similar idea of what happens (She swooped in to grab her child from the maw of an Alligator)

Swoop as defined by dictionary.reference.com (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/swoop) specifically also states that it's more of a diving motion than rising from below, which is what a shark would do.